# onAttach activity is null

Tags: android

In creation of a fragment, I encountered getActivity() to be null.
So to narrow down the problem, I kept a local copy of activity in onAttach(Activity activity), which by definition is when it is attached to an activity.

However, I logged the activity in onAttach, and it is still null.

I'm only running into this problem in 2.3.6 and below.

Is this a known problem with support package?

Comment: Does this happen after rotating the device? Anyways what happens if you wait for `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: This app in particular has rotation disabled. onActivityCreated() still has getActivity() as null, because previously I kept a local copy to find out where it is null. My UI manipulation is way passed that and getActivity() is still null.

Answer (score 9):

The series of methods called to bring a fragment up to resumed state are:

- onAttach(Activity) called once the fragment is associated with its activity.
- onCreate(Bundle) called to do initial creation of the fragment.
- onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.
- **onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().**
- onViewStateRestored(Bundle) tells the fragment that all of the saved state of its view hierarchy has been restored.
- onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).
- onResume() makes the fragment interacting with the user (based on its containing activity being resumed).

The **bold** method should be the one where getActivity doesn't return null anymore.

the **onAttach** method should not be used to call methods of the activity object, It should be used to initialise callback interfaces. An example of these interfaces can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface).

Comment: The fact is that it is null. I made sure to call super.onAttach first then tracked the the activity in the param of onAttach, it's null. It's a very small subset of our users with 2.3.6, which leads me to suspect that it's a bug. getActivity(), not just on onActivityCreated(Bundle), but all the way down to onResume, shows up as null, which is what prompted me to track at onAttach first.

Comment: I have been running similar code on a large set of 2.x devices. I used  to have similar nullpointers but those were solved by moving some code to the onResume().

Comment: Where is the point then to initialize the listeners in onAttach when they might be initialized from null and therefore stay null themselves.

Answer (score -3):

This problem is because of the support package it means the fragment are from android 3.0 and up that is API level 11 and UP so for sure you will face app crash for android 2.3.6 gingerbird

```
this.getActivity();
```

Comment: Mike already knows this is part of the support package and that is a link to your own blog, do you actually answer this question there? If so post the solution here, if not please delete this since you are just advertising and not answering the question.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, do your research, dont promote your own site

Comment: You should stop posting a link to your website **EVERY TIME** you post an answer. You should really stop promoting your website here.

Comment: i am not promoting my blog mike just helping

Comment: yeah J0k i will take care m not promoting any thing i m just helping