# Right place to hide or show the ActionBar in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have in several places in my apps the need to hide or show the action bar, the problem is that I am still not sure where is the best place to hide or show the `ActionBar` on the fragments.

I have only one activity and several different fragments, on some of them I need to completely hide the `ActionBar`, I succeeded to do it but I am concerned of the fact that this `ActionBar` is actually attached to the parent activity (I got some NullPointerException in the past ...).

So my question is, where should I hide or show my `ActionBar` when a fragment is added, and where should I hide or show it when the same fragments are removed?

For now I am thinking about for example hiding it in `OnActivityCreated`, and then showing it back in `onDetach` but I am afraid that the `ActionBar` would remain hidden for good if anything wrong happens in the fragment (and therefore `onDetach` is not called).

**UPDATE**: I had to do this in my code to avoid a null pointer on my fragment's `onStart` method:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    //if the actionbar exists
    if(getActivity().getActionBar() != null){
        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**:

I got actually this exception when trying to do it with `onAttach`: `requestFeature() must be called before adding content`. This error happened during screen rotations, I think the reason is that I am not using `setRetainInstance` and that the fragment is trying to add content to the main activity when this one is restarting due to the configuration change.

In order to fix that, I put my code in `onActivityCreated`, I guess I will only put this there for now on, and use on `onDetach` or `onDestroy` to display the `ActionBar` again.

Comment: you can do it in fragment also. `getActivity().getActionBar().hide()`

Comment: I know, this is what I do, my question is: where to do it in the Fragment's lifecycle?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same requirement in one project and I was able to hide/show the `ActionBar` inside a `Fragment` without inconvenients by using `onAttach` and `onDestroy` methods. Then, I use this to hide the actionbar when the fragment is created:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
}
```

And this, when it is removed:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
}
```

In the same methods, I was also able to `addFlags` and `clearFlags` to make the fragment in fullscreen mode. It worked well. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am a little bit concerned by the `onAttach` method, at this step, the `Activity` might not have been initialized yet, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553226/onattach-activity-is-null

Comment: @YoannHercouet I don't think it's really a problem, you need to be attached with the activity to call `getActivity` method and hide your actionbar. You don't need the view here, but the context. As I said, I did this before without any errors or issues. Here is [an example](https://github.com/Gitdefllo/FullScreenDownloader/blob/master/FullscreenDownloader/src/com/android/devdefllo/application/fullscreendownloader/FullScreenFragment.java).

Comment: Ok I just want to avoid to get a NullPointer there. About the `onDestroy` method, why not using `onDetach` instead as suggested by Libin in his answer?

Comment: @YoannHercouet As *Libin* said, when you use `setRetainInstance` in your fragment, the Docs says that it will not be called. However, in the example that I linked I used this method and also onDestroy and I never any problem. I think both can be used, it depends on your fragment behaviour.

Comment: I will try what you suggest but I still don't understand why I got some NullPointerExceptions in the `onStart` method in the past, I had to add a check to avoid it (I updated my question).

Comment: Maybe because onStart provide neither activity or context in its parameter. Then, your method getActivity and getActionBar are not related to the parent activity (- *I don't know, it's a suggestion*).

Comment: I upvoted both answers, I will keep a track with my bug reporter  to see if the null pointer happens again in `onAttach`. Merci!

Comment: De rien! And thank you. Keep in mind that even if I succeed with onDestroy and setRetainInstance, it will be better to follow the docs if you use the retain method in your fragment. We never know...

Comment: Last comment: why not using directly `activity.getActionBar().hide();` here since the activity is provided?

Comment: Indeed, good question! You're right, you can use this variable instead of the general var. I think it was an habit to me, I wrote like that. @YoannHercouet

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to  `Hide` when the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`. Since this the actual place where the `Fragment` is associated with the `Activity`

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {}
```

And, `Show` it back when the `Fragment` is detached from the `Activity`

```
public void onDetach() {}
```

Note: `onDestroy()` will not be called when you retrain the fragment instance , by setting `setRetainInstance`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use v4 support library this is the only way.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```