# getActivity() returns null in a view pager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two fragments in a view pager controlled by an activity IssueActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_issue);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    // progressBar.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(progressBar, params);
   // getProjects();
    fragment = new issuesFragment();

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("ISSUES");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("PROJECT");

}
```

This is the code that uses an interface to send list of projects to the issues or project fragment

```
private void lookForProjects() {
    showProgressBar();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    projects = new ArrayList<>();
    CollectionReference projectReference = db.collection(getString(R.string.collection_project));

    projectReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                hideProgressBar();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    Project project = snapshot.toObject(Project.class);
                    //projectNames[i] = project.getName();
                    projects.add(project);
                    //  i++;

                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: " + project.getName());
                }


                // setUpAdapterForAutoCompleteTextView(projectNames);
            } else {
               //if (progressBar != null) {
                //    hideProgressBar();
                //}
                //Toast.makeText(IssueActivity.this, "Cannot Load Projects", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            sendToFragments(projects);


        }
    });

}

private void sendToFragments(ArrayList<Project> projects) {
   // issuesFragment issueFragment = new issuesFragment();
    fragment.addProjects(projects);
  //  ProjectFragment projectFragment = new ProjectFragment();
  //  projectFragment.addProjects(projects);
}
```

but the issue here is this, in the issues fragment

```
fragment.addProjects(projects);
```

when on attach is called

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        issuesInterface = (issuesInterface)getActivity();

      //  Log.d(TAG, "addProjects: to know if fragment is added + " + isAdded());\
        getProjects();

    }
    catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The getActivity() returns a value, but when i want to use it to create an ArrayAdapter which is in a method nested in the getProject method

```
ArrayAdapter<String> issueSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,stuffs);
        issueSpinner.setAdapter(issueSpinnerAdapter);
```

it is null; and the app crashes with this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:233)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:181)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:139)
    at com.example.samuel.firestore.issuesFragment.initSpinner(issuesFragment.java:143)
    at com.example.samuel.firestore.issuesFragment.addProjects(issuesFragment.java:128)
    at com.example.samuel.firestore.Activities.IssueActivity.sendToFragments(IssueActivity.java:122)
    at com.example.samuel.firestore.Activities.IssueActivity.access$000(IssueActivity.java:31)
    at com.example.samuel.firestore.Activities.IssueActivity$1.onComplete(IssueActivity.java:112)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

but in a scenario, where nothing is sent from the controlling activity to the fragment, and I use a dummy string array to construct the adapter in the fragment,within the same method, i do not get any error and the adapter works just fine.
Can anyone help with the why when i try to get details from the Controlling activity and then try to construct an array adapter with results gotten, the getActivity returns null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onAttach activity is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553226/onattach-activity-is-null)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the fragment object I called the method sendToFragment on was not the fragment object I passed to the view pager adapter...once I changed it... and used the same object passed to the adapter to call my method on ..it started working ..

Answer (score -1):

getActivity() won't return non-null object until onAcitivtyCreated() callback method got called in Fragment.
In your case, if you want to communicate with the Activity, you'll have to do this in onAttach(). See below:

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        issuesInterface = (issuesInterface) context;
        getProjects();
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Or if you attach this fragment to another fragment you can use this:

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        issuesInterface = (issuesInterface) parent;
        getProjects();
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have done that..... the get project method simply calls the lookforProject method in the activity... and sends the arrayList of projects to the fragment by means of an interface ... when I log the value of getActivity in on Attach...it's non null,but when I try to call it in the method where I get my projects from the activity ... that's when it gives a null value , but whenever I don't send anything from the activity... the array adapter works just fine